# Changing pulumi stacks to another folder/repository

Tags: pulumi

Having a hard time trying to organize my stacks.

I would like to move the stack on top to the same repo/folder as the others, there's a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that to change that you need to change the stack tags pointing to the right repo.

You can change that by editing `gitHub:repo` and `vcs:repo` using this command `pulumi stack tag set`.

So setting those tags to `devops/infrastructure` did the job.

You can check you tags running `pulumi stack tag ls`.